# getting location of file

Tags: vb.net, filenames, dialog

I would like to know how I could build a dialogbox in VB.net that instead of opening a file can record its name and location?

Comment: Can you give more information to put your question in context? Some code you have written would help too.

Comment: Where do you want to record its name and location? The `OpenFileDialog` doesn't *automatically* open the file, it just gives the user a convenient way of picking the file out. It returns the name and location of the file to you as a property; just extract that and display it where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get a directoryinfo object with the path of the directory pointed to and then use the fileinfo to get the full name of the file that was selected.

Comment: Okay I am fiddling around with the following snippets of code however I need the file name restructured form the C:\MY FOLDER\MY FILE format to the C:\\MY FOLDER\\MY FILE format how can I do this?

Comment: this is done automatically when you get the filename from the fileinfo object, else you can do a simple replace of `\` to `\\`.